# What do "Goto Definition" and "Goto Reference" do in Sublime Text

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

What is the purpose of these commands?:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

As far as I know, this feature is only available if it's supported by the language you're using. For example, it's available with several bundled languages such as PHP or JavaScript.

When your cursor is over a function declaration (or when it's selected), you can use *Goto Reference* to jump to all calls of that function within your project. Using *Goto Definition* works the other way round, hover over a function call let's you jump to its definition.

Personally, I prefer using Sublime Text's tooltips that display definitions and references when hovering a function call.

**Example:**

[image]